# jQuery causes "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated" warning

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
var data = "<script src='some_script.js'></script><div class='content'> Some html content </div>";
$("#myDiv").html(data);
```

The content of the data variable is actually loaded through an ajax call but that is irrelevant to the question that is why I put it like this.

This seems to cause a "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated" warning, I tried to look it up online and some people say this is supposed to be fixed in jQuery 3 but even using the lastest jQuery version, I am still getting this warning which might become a real problem later.

Anyone know a way around that? I need the script to be executed as I insert my html. Script tags that do not point to an external file seem to work fine without warning.

Comment: If you're trying to load a JS file, use `getScript()` instead

Comment: That is not what I am trying to do. I am not trying to load just a script, I will edit my question for clarity. I am dynamically loading a bunch of html that happens to also have some scripts. I am not sure if this is good practice anyway (should the scripts always be in the <head>? But  it works well this way.

Comment: No, scripts don't always have to be in the `<head>` (in fact, most of the time it's better to place them at the end of the `<body>`), but *"loading a bunch of HTML that happens to also have some scripts"* is a questionable design decision to begin with. Instead of fixing the warning you might be better-off with changing your approach in such a way that loading arbitrary HTML that contains scripts is not longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Go through https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/ document, if you want to load script file dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

A simple pure javascript ajax function with status testing will solve your message problem. This message is there to prevent blocking if the ressources is not found (EQ: http status not **200**)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', 'some_script.js', true)
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText)
            myDiv.innerHTML = xhr.responseText
        }
    }
} 
xhr.send(null)
```

If your resource isn't found, the rest of your script won't fail.